# How to get the currently selected text in a CComboBoxEx?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, comboboxex

My first approach to the problem was to call the `GetWindowsText` method on the [CComboBoxEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccomboboxex-class?view=vs-2019) control, but I found that there is no associated text. After analyzing the control with [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) and reading some documentation on `CComboBoxEx`, I realised that these type of controls are only the parent of a classic [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019):

[image: Spy's screenshot]

I tried using the [`GetLBText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#getlbtext) method on the child ComboBox, passing [`GetCurSel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#getcursel) as an argument, but I only get some wrong text (the correct text should be "English"):

[image: Wrong text]

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you use `GetLBText` because that _is_ the appropriate function to use?

Comment: @acraig5075  I called the function like this: `CString szText; GetLBText(GetCurSel(), szText);`

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve text in comboBoxEx inherited class? Yes, then on any specific event?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade I'm trying to make a subclass of the child ComboBox, I need to recover the text during the OnPaint () message to be able to draw it manually.

Comment: [GetCurSel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#getcursel) returns `CB_ERR` in case no item is selected. If it returns a different value, pass that value to [GetLBText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#getlbtext). If that doesn't work for you, we'll need to see a [mcve].

Comment: @acraig5075 In the end `GetLBText()` was the right answer; I was just calling the method from the child `ComboBox`, and not the parent `ComboBoxEx`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @StefanoPittalis, It seems you inserted "English" on `ComboBox`, then you cannot use `GetWindowTextW()` because selected `HANDLE` is parent windows. (ID: Default 1001). You have to use `GetLBText()` to get current selected text. Would you like to post your full source code?

Comment: Also you can use `(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT))->GetSafeHwnd()` to control child `HWND`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is map the control to a `int` variable using **Class Wizard**:

[image: Class Wizard]

Now it is easy to access the selected text at any time. You need to use the [`GetItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccomboboxex-class?view=vs-2019#getitem) function. For example (code not tested):

```
COMBOBOXEXITEM cmbItem;
CString strText;

cmbItem.mask = CBEIF_TEXT;
cmbItem.iItem = m_cbItemIndex;
cmbItem.pszText = strText.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH);
m_cbMyCombo.GetItem(&cmbItem);
strText.ReleaseBuffer();
```

In short, you need to use the [`COMBOBOXEXITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-comboboxexitemw) and initialise it with the right flags to state what information you want to get from the extended combo. That, and the item index. Job done!

---

I realise that you have your own inherited class, but the mechanics are the same. You don't use `GetLBText`. You use the structure with the index and `GetItem` to get the selected text.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to retrieve the correct name; as you can see in the image below, the `ComboBox` is only a child of a `CombBoxEx32`:

[image]

I retrieved the pointer to the parent `ComboBoxEx32` from the child `ComboBox`, and searched for the text this way:

```
CString szText;
CComboBoxEx cbParentCombo ;
cbParentCombo.Attach( GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd()) ;
cbParentCombo.GetLBText( GetCurSel(), szText) ;
cbParentCombo.Detach() ;
```

My mistake was that I was calling `GetLBText()` directly from the child `ComboBox`, instead of the parent `CComboBoxEx`; because of that, all I was getting was some random gibberish. [GetLBText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#getlbtext) was indeed the correct solution.

Comment: Well done for coming up with a solution. I have added an answer that shows you how you are supposed to get the currently selected text from a `CComboBoxEx` object. Hope this helps!